# In python, how to group elements together, based on a key (group adjacent)?

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, split

In `python`, I'd like to group elements together based on a key (in example below, key is second element, or `element[1]`).

```
initial_array = [[10, 0], [30, 0], [40, 2], [20, 2], [90, 0], [80, 0]]
```

Only elements which keys are the same and that are adjacent should be grouped together.

```
splited_array = [ [[10, 0], [30, 0]], 
                  [[40, 2], [20, 2]], 
                  [[90, 0], [80, 0]] ]
```

Additionally, i'd like the element that caused the split to be also at the end of the previous array.

```
splited_array = [ [[10, 0], [30, 0], [40, 2]], 
                  [[40, 2], [20, 2], [90, 0]], 
                  [[90, 0], [80, 0]] ]
```

What is the easiest way to do that in python ? (re-using [Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) if possible)

Comment: I had temporarily changed the duplicate link on this to something that I thought was easier to understand, but it turns out that that version of the question had a different problem statement (and was in turn an inferior duplicate of something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lis = [[10, 0], [30, 0], [40, 2], [20, 2], [90, 0], [80, 0]]
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(lis, key=itemgetter(1))]
[[[10, 0], [30, 0]],
 [[40, 2], [20, 2]],
 [[90, 0], [80, 0]]]
```

For second one:

```
>>> ans = []
for k,g in groupby(lis, key=itemgetter(1)):
    l = list(g)
    ans.append(l)
    if len(ans) > 1:
        ans[-2].append(l[0])
...         
>>> ans
[[[10, 0], [30, 0], [40, 2]],
 [[40, 2], [20, 2], [90, 0]],
 [[90, 0], [80, 0]]]
```

**Update:**

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> lis = [[[10, 0], [30, 0]],
 [[40, 2], [20, 2]],
 [[90, 0], [80, 0]]]
>>> [x + ([y[0]] if y else []) for x,y in 
                                        zip_longest(lis,lis[1:])]
[[[10, 0], [30, 0], [40, 2]],
 [[40, 2], [20, 2], [90, 0]],
 [[90, 0], [80, 0]]]
```

Comment: just for someone curious about `itemgetter`: `itemgetter(i) = lambda x: x[i]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i'm just reading your (excellent) answer. for second part, isn't there a way to do that in less imperative style, eg : without modifying a global state (ans variable), but by using a set of functions that take and return new sets of data (just like groupby() function). Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. This is what i was looking for. Anyway, I get "ImportError: cannot import name izip_longest" when executing "from itertools import izip_longest" under Blender 2.67 (Python 3.3). I tried same code under ideone.com (online compiler with Python 3 support) but get same error message. Any idea ?

Comment: @tigrou use `zip_longest` in py3.x.